# I can't download macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I do not have "Install macOS Sierra.app" anywhere on my computer yet when I open the app store the button on macOS Sierra reads "open" instead of download. After I click open, nothing happens. I removed the cache folders of the app store and restart, the problem sticks.

Comment: @user3439894 couldn't find it but after I logged off and logged back in with my Apple account it worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after I logged off and logged back in with my Apple account it worked...